# Is there a Google API to identify how long an email address has been active?

Tags: email, google-api

I am working on a security feature in an app that ensures that the Google Authenticated user has had an email for x number of months.

Comment: As far as I am aware there is no such API... though why would you *want* such an API? Surely you should be checking how long a user has registered with *your* app, not how long the email address has existed...

Comment: Exactly, I am trying to ensure the person signing up to my app has had a email for more than 30 minutes.